# align of table fix with the navigation

Tags: html

I have this:

```
 <html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="../images/logo.ico" />
<title> About Dideban </title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td> <img src="../images/header.jpg" width="800" align="center"  /> </td>
</tr>
</table>


<table border="1" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:12; margin-left:130; margin-bottom:200">
<tr>
<td >
<br>
<b> txt </b> txt txt
<br>
txttxttxttxttxttxt
<br>
txttxttxttxttxt
<br>
txttxttxt
<br>
txttxttxttxttxttxttxttxt
<b> Snort </b>.
<br><br>
<b> Dideban Team </b>
<li> <font color="blue"> Manager: </font>&nbsp;&nbsp; Dr. Masood Hashemi</li>
<li> <font color="blue"> Designer&Developer:</font>txttxt</li>
<li> <font color="blue"> Supporter:</font>txttxt</li>
<li> <font color="blue"> Developer:</font> txttxt</li>
<li> <font color="blue"> Designer:</font> &nbsp;&nbsp; txttxttxt</li>
<br>

<!--<input class="but" type="button" value="close" onclick="window.close();" style="margin-top:200">-->

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<table cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td><img src="../images/footer.jpg" width="800" align="center"  /> </td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>
```

My problem is that when I see it the table is in the center and bottom of my above image
I want the table be in the left hand but when i tried align="left"
in the table tag nothing changed what can i do?
in my linux system it shows me right but in XP it is not fixed.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: why is the **body** tag placed between the tables.

Comment: because the image is in header

Comment: I think you misunderstand the part of **header** tag. The formating won't work until it isn't in **body**.

Comment: i think the html is not proper the header and footer tables also be included within body.

Comment: I put the body in the upper and I don't have header tag now but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert your "header" table in the **body** tag. The formating works only for tables that are within it. The **head** tag is not for your web page header. It's a header for a web browser to provide information about your page and etc - [more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp)

That should work:

```
<html>
<head />
<body>
 <table cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td> <img src="../images/header.jpg" width="800" align="center" /> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:12px; margin-left:130px; margin-bottom:200px">
  <tr>
   <td >
    <br>
    <b> Sometext </b> Sometext
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <table cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
   <td><img src="../images/footer.jpg" width="800" align="center"  /> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I don't understand anything after this edits. Everything looks fine. Remember that you have `margin-left:130` in your *content* table. This is why it is not glued to the left side of the page. Was that the case?

Comment: Now tell me another idea I try yours

Comment: I told you in the comment section Moyshe

Comment: Well, you told you don't have head tag, but after edits it appears you have it. You edit way too often and way too much. Revise your question before posting it and consider the point of it.

Comment: don't be angry I am sorry! I just wanted to keep up with coders who tell me ideas

Comment: I'm not angry. I'm confused;)

1. There are three tables in your code and I really don't know which one is the problem.

2. You edit so often and so much, that we can't follow the idea of your question.

3. It's not anger talking whrough my keys - it's will of helping you asking good questions;)

Also, did you check out my edit? Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I LOVE YOU this was the problem:D I forgot margin left!!! i didn't see it! Thank you APPROVED!

Comment: I am too weak and stupid in html codes actually design of the web:p

Answer (score 0):

The problems you are having with the browsers rendering your page differently are caused by errors in your code. The markup is not correct and the browsers have a hard time guessing what you actually want them to do.

Some of the problems with your code include:

- `<li>` tags with no `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent
- invalid style declarations: values should also include the measure units ( margin-left:130px; )

Instead of copying and pasting different solutions found over the internet, you should take your time and learn the basics of HTML. There are many tutorials on the web that are actually outdated by today's standards (the font tag is deprecated in HTML4 and should be replaced with CSS styles) so you should be careful in the resources you read.

This is a great resource for learning about HTML and it's relatives (CSS and JS):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn

You can also use this validate your code:
http://validator.w3.org/

If you don't take your time to learn the proper way of coding webpages, you will have no luck finding developers willing to help you.